# Android - Getting context of a fragment in a pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a android application using a pager as navigation. For the tabs I have 3 layouts as content. On one of the fragments is a gallery and I want to add images to it. For that I have to set an ImageAdapter but I need to know how to access the context of a fragment.

```
final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.pictures, null);
Gallery g = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext()));
```

I use this code above in the onCreate method to get the gallery from a layout that is not the contentview.
I have to give a Context to the ImageAdapter. But what context do I have to set there?

**EDIT:** This is my complete code:

```
package com.bw2801.uwelugemediathek;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
PicturesSectionFragment ps = new PicturesSectionFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.pictures, null);
    Gallery g = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ps.getActivity()));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.image01,
            R.drawable.image02,
            R.drawable.image03,
            R.drawable.image04,
            R.drawable.image05,
            R.drawable.image06,
            R.drawable.image07,
            R.drawable.image08,
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        return i;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new DummySectionFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SoundSectionFragment();
            case 2:
                return ps;
        }
        return new DummySectionFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Informationen";
        case 1:
            return "Soundboard";
        case 2:
            return "Galerie";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
    }
}

public static class PicturesSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public PicturesSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures, container, false);
    }
}

public static class SoundSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public SoundSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sounds, container, false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I actually got my answer from your question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fragments don't have their own Context, they use parent Activity.

- To get parent Activity Context, use `getActivity()`
- To use Application Context, use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Prefer Application Context wherever possible.

**UPDATE:**

`getActivity()` of a Fragment returns an Activity instance **if and only if**, the said Fragment is currently attached to an Activity.

---

So,

```
Fragment f = new MyFragment();
```

creates a fragment, but it is not attached to an activity yet. Hence `f.getActivity()` returns `null`.

---

After its added to an activity:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(f,"fragment").commit();
```

Now, `getActivity()` will return an Activity instance.

---

Again, if we detach the fragment from Activity:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(f).commit()
```

`getActivity()` will again return a `null` value.

---

So, we should not use `getActivity()` outside the `Fragment` class, because we can't be sure of attached status. Thus I'll advice you to used `getActivity()` inside the fragment's own class in its methods: `onAttach()`, `onCreate()` or `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I did it like this but it causes a nullpointerexception: `PicturesSectionFragment ps = new PicturesSectionFragment();` and later in the code: `new ImageAdapter(ps.getActivity().getApplicationContext())`

Comment: `ps.getActivity()` seems to be null. I logged it and it was `null`.

Comment: @bw2801 You are calling `getActivity()` at wrong place and at wrong time. See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can use like this

```
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Comment: i mean you want to create a new instant for ImageAdaptor it requires Context. if it correct my code will work..

Comment: getActivity() seems to return null. Do you have any idea, why?

Comment: Show your code where you used, and Where you want to sue this.

Comment: I logged `ps.getActivity()` and it returned null.

Comment: try like this g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

Comment: The gallery page is still blank.

Comment: So your problem solved how to pass context, now you have problem with your galley iamges.

Comment: But what is wrong here? The images are in the `drawable-hdpi` folder

Comment: In your code your are attaching layout to tab activity, it's not correct, you have to add gallery to one of your Fragments it will work.

Comment: How do I add the gallery to the fragment? I don't get it.

Comment: just create a layout with gallery, get gallery view in the onCreateView() of fragment. add adapter to that view in the fragment.

Comment: llok at this examples http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/ http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most precise way to get the context of the fragment that I found is to get it directly from the ViewGroup when you call onCreateView method at least here you are sure not to get null for getActivity()

```
public class Animal extends Fragment {

Context thiscontext;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     thiscontext = container.getContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   write under code in Your CoreApplication.java

    step1) 
    public class CoreApplication extends Application {

    private static CoreApplication instance; 
    }

    step2) onCreate(){

    instance = this;

    }



    step3 )
    add under method()
```

public static CoreApplication getGlobalApplicationContext() {

```
    if (instance == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("this application does not 
    inherit GlobalApplication"); " +
    "}

    return instance;
    }

    Step4)
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getGlobalApplicationContext()));
```