# How do I dismiss a DialogFragment from an Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment over an Activity.  This DialogFragment is a listview populated by a web service call.  Upon clicking a row in this listview, the dialog should disappear and the Activity resumes with a String passed from the adapter via the 'fragment interface pattern'.  I have the following adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
....

// Activity implements this interface to use callback and get id value
public interface MyDialogListener {
    void onFinishMyDialog(String id);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Profile selectedProfile = getItem(position);
    String selectedProfileID = selectedProfile.getId();

    // fragments dont have their own context, get Activity fragment belongs to
    Context context = getContext();
    MyDialogListener listener = (MyDialogListener)context;

    listener.onFinishMyDialog(selectedProfileID);
    /* NO ACCESS TO FRAGMENT, CANNOT DO THIS
    dismiss(); */
}
```

How can I dismiss the dialog fragment and have control go back to the Activity?  I cannot aceess the fragment from a context since they don't have one([Android - Getting context of a fragment in a pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848809/android-getting-context-of-a-fragment-in-a-pager))

Answer (score 4):

pass one `interface` (with rowClicked(Object object))from fragment to adapter for notify fragment which row is clicked.
NOTE : also you can pass one interface (with dismissed(Object object)) from activity to fragment for notify activity when dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to your adapter as follows.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile> implementsapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    Dialog dialog;
    ....
    MyAdapter(Dialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }
}
```

Now call dialog.dismiss() whereever you want to dismiss the dialog in the adapter.

Comment: In case this helps for Kotlin users, passing the fragment in the class constructor declaration `class SomeAdapter(private val fragment: SomeFragment) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.SomeHolder>() {` also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make dialog static and then you will be able to dismiss it any where

Might be it will help you

Comment: Please do not suggest use of static object, its risky whenever your activity will destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your activity object in your adapter constructor, call method from your adapter for dismiss dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**1: Pass PopUpFragment Context to adapter**

```
public class PopUpFragment extends DialogFragment {
        //pass PopUpFragment Context to adapter
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(PopUpFragment.this);
        }
```

**2: Initialize PopUpFragment object on construstor and dismiss the dialog fragment**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile> implementsapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    PopUpFragment fragment;

    //initialize PopUpFragment object on construstor
    MyAdapter(PopUpFragment dialog) {
        this.fragment= dialog;
    }

    onclick{
    //dismiss dialog on click
    fragment.dismiss();
    }
}
```